# How much of mongo shell command's javascript part executed is on server?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is all of the javascript part in mongo shell commands executed on the server or on client or is it partial?

Let's say I have a command

```
db.mycollection.find({timestamp:{$lt:new Date()}}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.mycollection.remove(doc);
})
```

1. Is the `new Date()` executed on the client or on server?
2. Is the `forEach` part executed on the client or on the server?

Comment: Its a perfectly valid question, I don't understand the downvote :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to execute the above code into mongo shell and enable the mongodb [profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) on the server on level 2, it records only following operations:

- db.mycollection.find({timestamp:{$lt:new Date()}})
- db.mycollection.remove(doc)

The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB.

- Is the new Date() executed on the client or on server? - On client
- Is the forEach part executed on the client or on the server? - On client

You can notice the CPU utilization by mongo process on client if it processes large data.

You can also check this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297025/mongodb-server-side-javascript-is-client-side-actually).